# pytorch sparse (sparse_coo_tensor) broadcast dense shape in multiplication

Tags: pytorch, broadcast

Using broadcasting in normal tensors, the following works

```
torch.ones(3, 1)*torch.ones(3, 10)
```

I need to extend this behavior to sparse vectors, but I can't:

```
i = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1],
                  [2, 0, 2]])
a = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i, torch.ones(3, 1), [2, 4, 1])
b = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i, torch.ones(3, 10), [2, 4, 10])
a*b
# gives RuntimeError: mul operands have incompatible sizes
```

Why shouldn't this work?
Is there an pytorch function to do this?
If not what is the best alternative algorithm?

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to create sparse tensors with sizes `(3, 1)` and `(3, 10)`, or are you intentionally creating the sparse tensors of sizes `(2, 4, 1)`, and `(2, 4, 10)`, respectively? Note that the order in the docs is [`torch.sparse_coo_tensor(indices, values, size=None [,...])`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.sparse_coo_tensor). I'm still having the same issue when doing it the other way, so it does not affect the actual question, just the precise formulation.